# React leaflet on right click event

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible within react leaflet to know when a right click occurs on the map?

Currently, the onClick handler will send an event and the type will be "click"

```
<Map
    ref="map"
    preferCanvas={true}
    viewport={this.props.viewport}
    onClick={(e) => this.onClickHandler(e)}
>
```

The event from the onClick will return an object that includes "type":"click"; not specifying the  left or right etc.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/50017/111968

Comment: The above link does not utilize the react-leaflet framework. I am looking specifically for react-leaflet

Answer (score 0):

For anyone investigating this issue in the future, here are the `React-Leaflet` docs for specifying handlers:

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/